# MACRO to create a table in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi everyone thanks so much for taking the time to read this.

I'd like to create a macro in Teradata that will create a table from another table based on specific parameters.

My original table consists of three columns patient_id, diagnosis_code and Date_of_birth
......

I'd like to build a macro that would allow me to specify a diagnosis code and it would then build the table consisting of data of all patients with that diagnosis code.

My current code looks like this

```
Create Macro All_pats (diag char) as (
create table pats as(
select *
from original_table 
where diag = :diagnosis_code;)
with data primary index (patid);
```

I cant seem to get this to work - any tips?

Thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a semicolon in a wrong place and a missing closing bracket:

```
Create Macro All_pats (diag char) as (
  create table pats as
   (
    select *
    from original_table 
    where diag = :diagnosis_code
   ) with data primary index (patid);
);
```

Edit:

Passing multiple values as a delimited list is more complicated (unless you use Dynamic SQL in a Stored Procedure):

```
REPLACE MACRO All_lpats (diagnosis_codes VARCHAR( 1000)) AS
(
  CREATE TABLE pats AS
   (
     SELECT *
     FROM original_table AS t
     JOIN TABLE (StrTok_Split_To_Table(1, :diagnosis_codes, ',')
                 RETURNS (outkey INTEGER,
                          tokennum INTEGER,
                          token VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET Unicode)
                ) AS dt
     ON t.diag = dt.token
   ) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (patid);
);

EXEC All_lpats('111,112,113');
```

As the name implies `StrTok_Split_To_Table` splits a delimited string into a table. You might need to adust the delimiter and the length of the resulting token.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response - you absolutely nailed it! 
May I be slightly more of a pain and ask one follow up 

how would I modify this to enable me to have multiple diagnosis codes - i.e I want it to create a table where the diagnosis code is 111 or 112 or 113?

Thank you again

Comment: @willepi: Added an example using `StrTok_Split_To_Table`.