# SQL Teradata Variable Input

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm currently writing a statement in which often times a few variables are given in as parameter, so I wanted to not code those in, rather make a pop up when I execute the statement. Like you can see in the Picture.
[Pop Up window for inout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWdMu.png)

Now this works if I code:
WHERE x.test =  '?InputVar1'

and put in one variable in.
I want to be able to put in more than one.
I tried replacing = with IN and type in more variables in the pop up seperated by a ",", didnt display the data even though I thinks rows were processed.

I hope a made my problem clear and hoping for some advice. I'm really new in SQL and teradata. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

This *variable* is simply used for a *Search & Replace*, when `test` is actually a VarChar you have to key in `foo','bar` (without the outermost quoteswhich are already around `'?InputVar1'`.

Might be easier to define it as `WHERE x.test IN (?InputVar1)` and then specifiy `'foo','bar'`.

When it's numeric `1,2,3,4` will work.

Comment: what does foo and bar mean?

Comment: where do I put this?

WHERE fp.pnrRecordLocator IN                         
 
 ('?InputVar1')

i will put in variables like: B37UK5

Comment: Yes, that's what you wrote in your question.

Comment: So how would the statement with foo bar in it be correct?

Comment: `IN (?InputVar1)` ->  `'foo','bar'`, `IN ('?InputVar1')` ->  `foo','bar`

Comment: So then I can type in one by one my variables, depending on how often I code this.
I wanted to have the pop up only once and be able to paste up to 20 variables in there at once

Comment: Come on, try it. This is what you key in the popup: either `'foo','bar'` or `foo','bar` depending on how you defined the variable.

Comment: Showing an error message without the SQL is useless.

Comment: WHERE fp.pnrRecordLocator 
 
 IN ((?InputVar1) ->  foo','bar)

Comment: Last try: This is your SQL: `WHERE fp.pnrRecordLocator IN (?InputVar1)` and this is what you key into the popup: `'foo','bar'`

Comment: Ich kann mich nur wiederholen: Das steht im SQL code `WHERE fp.pnrRecordLocator IN (?InputVar1)` und das tippst du genauso inklusive der Hochkommas in das Popop-Fenster ein: `'foo','bar'`

Comment: und wo kommen meine parameter rein?

Comment: `'foo','bar','bla',fasel'` **sind** deine Parameter, soviele du willst.

Comment: jetzt macht es sinn :D
zu definieren dass die hochkommas immer gesetzt sind und nur mit einem komma im pop up zu trennen ist nicht möglich?

Comment: Der Editor macht einfach ein Suchen und Ersetzen und was dabei rauskommt muss gültiges SQL sein. Eventuell möglich wäre das über `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574915/macro-to-create-a-table-in-sql, aber da sind die paar Hochkommas einfacher. Bei nicht-Strings geht das sowieso...